# Replacement for combine: function for Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

I am using a Swift 3 project which initialises the variable something like:

```
let recordingAverageLevel = recordingIntervals.reduce(0.0, combine: +) / Double(recordingIntervals.count)
```

When converting to Swift 4 the above initialisation throws error like:

> Argument labels '(_:, combine:)' do not match any available overloads

What is the replacement of the combine: function in Swift 4?

Comment: Why not let Xcode's code completion do it for you?

Comment: FYI - I suspect that all of the down votes are because you could have solved this yourself very easily by simply looking at the documentation for the `reduce` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
let recordingAverageLevel = recordingIntervals.reduce(0.0,+) / Double(recordingIntervals.count)
```

here I suppose

```
var recordingIntervals = [Double]()
```